# OS X Mail - How can I setup multiple e-mail addresses under the same mail account?

Tags: macos, mail.app

OS X Mail - How can I setup multiple e-mail addresses under the same mail account?

I use two addresses with the same account one is me@myworkdomain.com and the other is me@mypersonaldomain.com. On iOS I can add the second address to the mail account configuration and I can send from both.

How is this done on OS X's Apple Mail?

Comment: This no longer works under Sierra.
Has anyone found a way to accomplish the same thing using Mac Mail under Sierra?

Comment: @elipsett In Sierra, you add additional email aliases by going to the same dialog, then selecting "Edit Email Addresses" from what is now the Email Address dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add another email address to an account you add it to the email field.

Each address is separated by a comma.  ","

But note just because you can add it does not mean you email provider will accept an address from a different provider/domain.

[image]

Edit: As of macOS Sierra, the procedure is slightly different. The "Email Address" field is now a dropdown, and you add additional addresses by selecting "Edit Email Addresses..." from this dropdown.